# How to filter a data object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Context**: I receive from Elasticsearch the result of a search (example below) which I put into a Vue.js `data` object. I then list the data via `<div v-for="result in results">{{result.name}}</div>`.

```js
var vm = new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
    results: [{
        'name': 'john',
        'big': true
      },
      {
        'name': 'jim',
        'tall': true
      },
      {
        'name': 'david'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.3.3/vue.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <div v-for="result in results">{{result.name}}</div>
</div>
```

I now would like to filter the results. To do so, I will have switches which will be [bound via `v-model`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio).

**Question: what is the correct way to handle filtering in Vue.js?**

I would like to render (via a `v-if`, I guess) only elements from `results` which match a filter (say, `big` is checked - so only `john`should be visible), or a concatenation of filters (logical `AND`).

The part I have a hard time turning into Vue.js philosophy is "display the element if all active switches are present (value `true`) in that element).

Since I am sure that having a chain of `v-if`s is not the right approach, I prefer to ask before jumping into that (and I would probably rather rerun a search with parameters than go this way - but I would prefer to avoid the search way).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a computed property which returns only the filtered results:

```
computed: {
  filteredResults() {
    return this.results.filter((result) => {
      // your filter logic, something like this:
      // return result.big || result.tall
    });
  }
}
```

And use it in the `v-for` instead:

```
<div v-for="result in filteredResults">{{result.name}}</div>
```